# "Object required" error in VBA but I'm using Set to assign object

Tags: vba, excel

I have this function:

```
Public Function nextBlock(featureBlockObj As FeatureBlock, endFeatureNumber As Variant) As FeatureBlock

Dim downstreamFeatureNumber As Variant

'get the feature number that this endpoint connects to
downstreamFeatureNumber = featureBlockObj.connectedFeatureNumber(endFeatureNumber)

'if it connects to a feature number, look that feature number up in blockDict
If isNumericNonBlank(downstreamFeatureNumber) Then
    Set nextBlock = blockDict(downstreamFeatureNumber)
'if it does not connect, this is the last block in the sequence
Else
    Set nextBlock = Nothing
End If

End Function
```

`blockDict` is a Dictionary; `FeatureBlock` is a user-defined class.

This line:

```
Set nextBlock = blockDict(downstreamFeatureNumber)
```

is throwing the error:

```
Object required.
```

I've verified the following:

- `downstreamFeatureNumber` exists as a key in `blockDict`
- `blockDict(downstreamFeatureNumber)` is an object of type `FeatureBlock`

So why can't I assign the `blockDict()` reference to `nextBlock` using `Set`?

Comment: Where do you define and set “blockDict”?

Comment: Where and how is `nextBlock` declared?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, the `blockDict(downstreamFeatureNumber)` Is Nothing and this is your problem. You need to qualify it before attempting to assign to `nextBlock` (if it should not happen then it is an entirely different issue-- not a VBA problem).

```
If isNumericNonBlank(downstreamFeatureNumber) _
    AND (Not (blockDict(downstreamFeatureNumber) Is Nothing)) Then
```

Comment: There does appear to be a problem with `blockDict(downstreamFeatureNumber)`.  I'll try to isolate what's going on and revise the question as a self-contained example.